# Disbale tablesorter from sorting by clicking on header but stil support sort by drop down option

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I have found this example in stackoverflow. This is very helpful.

http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/Yke6M/

Right now it allows two ways to sort table contents:

1) sort by clicking on each table  header
2) sort the table by  selecting a option  drop down.

My requirement is only sort with drop down menu.
 I want to remove the feature of  sorting by clicking on table header.

can i disable clicking on header?

I am guessing that I can  add some css to table header which makes it unclickable. But I dont know if there is something like that in css.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is set the sorter to false for each column:

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    headers : {
        0 : { sorter: false },
        1 : { sorter: false },
        2 : { sorter: false },
        3 : { sorter: false }
    }
});
```

This disables the manual sorting, but you can still trigger a sort, so the external dropdown will still work ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/Yke6M/31/)).

Or if you are using my fork of [tablesorter on github](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-class-name.html), you can just add the class name `sorter-false` to the headers ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/Yke6M/32/)):

```
<th class="sorter-false">Alphabetic</th>
<th class="sorter-false">Numeric</th>
<th class="sorter-false">Animals</th>
<th class="sorter-false">Sites</th>
```

Comment: I am doing the same thing,I even copied the code from the Fiddle but upon setting {sorter : false } it disables sort on the dropdown as well.

Comment: Update...that's very wierd I used your fork of tablesorter and it started to work...Thanks You are a genius !!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a kind of hack. I created duplicate rows on which i have to sort. I am hiding them. So now I made sort disable on all rows i am showing.

So as i have the same columns as duplicates which are hidden so i am able to get sorting and also no one can sort by clicking the table header